# Group column from CSV file and concatenate values of another column

Tags: csv, powershell

I am just getting started with PowerShell and can not find an answer to this anywhere.
Trying to write a script that imports a CSV file and searches through the file to see if any names are the same. If the names are the same I want to write all of those values together on the same line and only show the name once.

For example:

```
Name   Number    
Tom    1  
Tom    4  
Bill   3  
Dave   2  
Dave   5   
Dave   6
```

With this output:

```
Tom- The number(s) associated with this person is/are: 1/4  
Bill- The number(s) associated with this person is/are: 3  
Dave- The number(s) associated with this person is/are: 2/5/6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipeline like this should do the job

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv |   
  Group-Object Name |  
  Foreach-Object { 
    $nums = $_.Group.Number;
    "{0}- The number(s) associated with this person is/are: {1}" -f $_.Name, ($nums -join '/') 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

less elegant version

```
$Data = Import-Csv .\test.csv
$hash = @{}
$output = @()
foreach ($name in $data) {
$hash[$name.name] += $name.number+"/"
}
foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
$values = $hash[$key] -replace ("/$")
$output += "$key - The number(s) associated with this person is/are: $values"
}
$output
```