# Group column from CSV file and concatenate values of another column, and export back to CSV

Tags: list, powershell, csv, group-by

This is a follow up to this:
[In PowerShell, how can I get the XML inner child to populate its parents and format it in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041817/in-powershell-how-can-i-get-the-xml-inner-child-to-populate-its-parents-and-for)

And it's related to this question:
[Group column from CSV file and concatenate values of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113586/group-column-from-csv-file-and-concatenate-values-of-another-column)
and this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table

My purpose is to grab my csv file and group by the "company" name, and I don't know where to start, I know that PS has a "Group-Object" CmdLet but it returns me an object that I don't know how to deal with.

So, using the example columns that I had before, Harvey from Specter would get from:

| PName | Company | ORDERDATE | STREET1 | City | ProjectName | Name | Color | OtherData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Charles | Contoso | 2022-01-25 | FakeStreet 123 | San Francisco | Sacramento Expansion | ProductA | Lemon | OtherData |
| Harvey | Specter | 2022-01-25 | NotAFake 123 | San Diego | North Dakota Expansion | ProductA | Red | OtherData |
| Harvey | Specter | 2022-01-25 | NotAFake 123 | San Diego | North Dakota Expansion | ProductB | Blue | OtherData |

To:

| PName | Company | ORDERDATE | STREET1 | City | ProjectName | Name | Color | OtherData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Charles | Contoso | 2022-01-25 | FakeStreet 123 | San Francisco | Sacramento Expansion | ProductA | Lemon | OtherData |
| Harvey | Specter | 2022-01-25 | NotAFake 123 | San Diego | North Dakota Expansion | ProductA, **ProductB** | Red, **Blue** | OtherData |

Thanks and as always, appreciated

Comment: This is doable but, say for example you group by Company, and then you have 2 objects, what happens if OrderDate is different? What should happen in that case?

Comment: Hi Santiago! Thanks again for trying to help out, for this particular thing all the dates are going to be the same, the XML are retrieved daily and they share the date anyways.

Comment: The closest I've got is after grouping I run a foreach-object but of course I ended up with columns where you've got things like this:  
Name:
{Cody Flora, Cody Flora, Cody Flora}

Comment: I tried to do Group-Object -Property Company and then a new object, using a "$_.Group.PName[0]", but if the group has a single entity then it's treated as a string and only returns the first letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your last question and assuming you already have `$result` stored, this is how you can **update** the object you already have with the help of `Group-Object`:

```
$result | Group-Object Company | ForEach-Object {
    # If the group is 1 object return it and skip next logic
    if($_.Count -eq 1) { return $_.Group }
    # Capture all objects of this group
    $thisGroup = $_.Group
    
    # We know if we are here that `$thisGroup` is an object[],
    # there is at least more than 1 object.
    # `$thisObject[0]` is the object we want to update, so,
    # `$thisObject[0].PropertyName` will enumerate ALL Values
    # of "PropertyName" and we can join them with `-join` and assign
    # the result to the 1st Object
    $thisGroup[0].Name  = $thisGroup.Name -join ', ' # Join these elements
    $thisGroup[0].Color = $thisGroup.Color -join ', '
    # Return ONLY the first object of this object[], this is the
    # object that was updated.
    $thisGroup[0]
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Using the same XML and my previous answer to construct `$result`, the output from above code would be:

```
PName   Company ORDERDATE  STREET1        City          ProjectName            Name               Color     OtherData
-----   ------- ---------  -------        ----          -----------            ----               -----     ---------
Charles Contoso 2022-01-25 FakeStreet 123 San Francisco Sacramento Expansion   ProductA           Lemon     OtherData
Harvey  Specter 2022-01-25 NotAFake 123   San Diego     North Dakota Expansion ProductA, ProductB Red, Blue OtherData
```

Comment: Thanks Santi, I was using the index [0], but in the wrong place! Que boludo!